# How can I get pending transactions from Eth mempool using websockets RPC?

Tags: web3.py, python

I am using Rivet WebSockets RPC call with web3.py to get pending transactions in Ethereum mempool.

https://rivet.cloud/docs/topics/api/ws.html#newpendingtransactions

This is the code I have used so far. But the call returns an error

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import statistics

rivet = 'wss://b9e4817100b74cd3b72e486fd79d4a06.eth.ws.rivet.cloud/'
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(rivet))

pending_transactions = web3.provider.make_request("eth_subscribe", 
"newPendingTransactions")
print(pending_transactions)
```

Error: {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 0, 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'non-array args'}}

What is wrong here? How can I proceed. Need help!

Comment: the subscription mechanism doesn't work for getting  ALL transactions from tx pool as they arrive to it. However there is a backend funcitonality implemented (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0a68558e7e025afebf67b81bf48ecb8b0fa7c06d/eth/api_backend.go#L278), so you can extend it yourself by modifying Geth

Comment: the pending transaction functionality in Ethclient is only for getting your own pending transactions, but not everybody's transactions

Comment: you either get all transaction on each RPC request or modify `geth` to work in subscription mode

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how subscribe works. I was looking for something similar to parity_pendingTransactions which returns an array of pending transactions in the mempool. In rivet, I find only  eth_pendingTransactions method which returns pending transactions from my node.